# I am trying to scanf a string and put it in a function, but it doesn't work

Tags: c

Initially it worked fine

```
int function(char *pointer, char *pointer0){
    if(pointer[0]==pointer0[0]){
        printf("Same");
    }
    else{
        printf("Not same");
    }
}

int main(){
    char string;
    function("example","echinodermata");
    return 0;
    }
```

But, when i tried to convert it to take user input, it doesn't work correctly and i don't understand why, how do i fix this?

```
int function(char *pointer, char *pointer0){
    printf("%s %s\n",pointer,pointer0);
    if(pointer[0]==pointer0[0]){
        printf("Same");
    }
    else{
        printf("Not same");
    }
}

int main(){
    char string,string0;
    scanf("%s",&string);
    scanf("%s",&string0);
    function(&string,&string0);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize the question by removing it just because it had a simple solution. I did a rollback of your edit. If you wish, we can close it as "simple typo" though.

Comment: How do you define "working" here? Do you expect strings to be equal? Note you're comparing pointers, not content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a mistake in this case. You haven't defined any array length for `string` and `string0` variables which are declared as a single `char`. If you do something like:

```
char string[10], string0[10]; // array length defined
```

Secondly, you had used the placeholder `%s` with `char` data-type only, so you must use array for accepting multiple characters.

It'll work.

Comment: It has a time limit, don't worry i will